# spring interceptor doesn't add header to @RestController services

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http, interceptor

I have following interceptor:

```
public class SecurityInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    }
}
```

I checked - spring invokes its on each http resquest.

I notice strange thing. It works fine for controllers like this:

```
@Controller
public class AdminViewController {
    @GetMapping ("data")
    public String dataTemplate() {
        return "data";
    }
}
```

[image]

But it doesn't add response header to controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Constants.MY_API_URL)
public class DataServiceController {
     @PostMapping(value = "/mapping", consumes = "application/json")
     public ResponseEntity<Void> saveMapping(@RequestBody MappingDTO mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...
        return new ResponseEntity<>(CREATED);
    }
}
```

[image]

But I can't explain it because interceptor is invoking.

How can I add header for all request responses?

Comment: @pvpkiran, I understand but it would be better to do it in the only place

Comment: @pvpkiran, also I have method which returns deferredResult. It doesn't work expected too

Comment: Another piece of information. If you were to return 404 or some error code instead of Created or OK, then the header is added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is working I've created filter:

```
public class SecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        httpResponse.setHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "DENY");
        filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }
}
```

and registered:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean dawsonApiFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new SecurityFilter());
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`HandlerInterceptorAdapter`s can not working with `@ResponseBody` and `ResponseEntity` methods because those are handled by `HttpMessageConverter` which writes to response before `postHandle` is called which makes it difficult to change the response.

Instead you can write a `ResponseBodyAdvice` and mark it as `@ControllerAdvice` to add the header you want.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseDTOFilterAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(final MethodParameter returnType, final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(final Object body, final MethodParameter returnType, final MediaType selectedContentType,
        final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, final ServerHttpRequest request,
        final ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (body instanceof ResponseEntity) {
            ResponseEntity responseEntity = (ResponseEntity) body;
            responseEntity.getHeaders().add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
        }
        return body;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can `response.getHeaders().add(headerName, headerValue);` in beforeBodyWrite if body is not instance of ResponseEntity.

Answer (score 2):

Sir, For specific controller you can try this procedure

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(Constants.MY_API_URL)
     public class DataServiceController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/mapping", consumes = 
     "application/json")
     public ResponseEntity<Boolean> 
     saveMapping(@RequestBody MappingDTO mapping) {
     .........
     ...........
     ......
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
       return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(true, headers, 
        HttpStatus.OK);
     }
      }
```

Or

If you have spring security in your application add this one inside security configuration file .So we can disable xframe option  globally for each request response

```
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

Or

PostHandle method of HandlerInterceptor is not always ideally suited for use with @ResponseBody and ResponseEntity methods. In such cases an HttpMessageConverter writes to and commits the response before postHandle is called which makes it impossible to change the response, for example to add a header. Instead an application can implement ResponseBodyAdvice and either declare it as an @ControllerAdvice bean or configure it directly on RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.

https://mtyurt.net/post/spring-modify-response-headers-after-processing.html

Or

@gstackoverflow post owner already find out solution .We can refer his solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late but u can add header on preHandle then get and post method will work.